# what is the correct syntax here? getting type TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, nosql, pymongo

```
query={"colourCode" : "orange" },{"createdOn":{ "$gt" : my_datetime}},{"assignmentRef":{'$ne':None}}

cursor = collection.find({query},{'createdOn':1,'assignmentRef.name':1,'_id':0,'colourCode':1})


list_cur = list(cursor)

df = DataFrame(list_cur)
print(df)

Result

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

what is the problem here? please rewrite the code with correct syntax, so that I clearly can understand it.

Comment: Which line is emitting this error? And also is your `query` really a tuple of dicts, as you have given here?

Comment: @khelwood first line query is getting error, what could be the solution?

Comment: Seems like query should be a (single) dictionary. You can't merge the collection of dictionaries stored in the variable `query` into a single dictionary just by wrapping it in `{}` like `{query}`

Comment: @HenryEcker please provide correct syntax for {query}  
please write the code here. so that i can compare your synax vs my syntax for query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues; the query needs to be constructed as a dictionary (yours creates a tuple), and the first parameter of the find needs to just be `query` not `{query}`.

This should be closer to what you need:

```
import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
collection = db.mycollection
my_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

query = {"colourCode": "orange", "createdOn": {"$gt": my_datetime}, "assignmentRef": {'$ne': None}}

cursor = collection.find(query, {'createdOn': 1, 'assignmentRef.name': 1, '_id': 0, 'colourCode': 1})

list_cur = list(cursor)

df = DataFrame(list_cur)
print(df)
```

Comment: it worked thanks, dude.  
in my code query is the wrong syntax